# asp.net mvc relative pathproblem

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I used template in my asp.net mvc project. I copied all the template index file into _layout.cshtml
and after that I changed the path of the css file but its not working.

```
<!-- Template Stylesheet -->
<link href="../admin/dashmin-1.0.0/css/style.css" asp-append-version="true" rel="stylesheet">
```

it only works if change relative path to wwwroot/css/site.css

how can I fix this problem?